# Is the non-open port response [RST, ACK] normal?

Tags: networking, tcp

When the server port is not open then receive the [SYN] header TCP, is the response of [RST, ACK] normal?

[image: t]

Comment: You asked "is the response of [SYN,ACK] normal" but the image shows "RST, ACK". Are you asking if the image is right or if the image is wrong, or something else?

Comment: Changed it, thanks your remind.